# CoreData leak when reading a property

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have the following code in a loop iterating over the different `document` objects:

```
NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSData* data = [document primitiveValueForKey:@"data"];
[document.managedObjectContext refreshObject:document mergeChanges:NO];
[pool release];
```

The "data" property is a large blob (a 1MB image).
And as I monitor the memory with the Allocation Instrument memory usage is increasing. I cannot find where the leak is coming from and how to remove it.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see *data* assigned anywhere.

Comment: good point. @Kamchatka, you are getting the value for the key `data` but not setting it to anything.

Comment: I want to read the value of data from CoreData and dump it to a file. That's why I'm not assigning any value to it.

Comment: Sorry my code was incorrect. I cleaned it up while copy pasting and forgot the assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by doing : `[document.managedObjectContext processPendingChanges]` right before draining the pool. However, I don't understand what pending changes would be there? Could someone enlighten me on that?

Comment: It might be because you are setting the flag of mergeChanges, setting it to NO will create a new fault that will create a new object when accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your sample code, did you mean:

```
NSData *data = [document primitiveValueForKey:@"data"];
```

As data is currently not assigned within the scope of your autoreleasepool it is also not released with with your autoreleasepool

Why are you using [primitiveValueForKey](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/primitiveValueForKey%3a) and not a dynamic accessor?

> The dynamic accessors are much more
>   efficient, and allow for compile-time
>   checking.

Comment: You are correct, I changed the code. My actual code does the assignment to "data". I'm not using the dynamic accessors because I'm doing a migration. The dynamic accessors will read that "data" from the file I'm writing too during the migration. But during the migration, the source of "data" is the data field in the old CoreData Sqlite database.

Answer (score 0):

How about calling `[pool drain]` instead of `[pool release]`?

Comment: How would that help? Don't they have a similar behavior on iOS?

Comment: Sorry, missed the part about non-gc environment. Disregard my answer (or downvote it).

Answer (score 0):

Your observation that `processPendingChanges` seems to solve the problem suggests to me that, as you import, the UndoManager for your NSManagedObjectContext is keeping track of all the changes you make as you do your bulk import.

What `processPendingChanges` is doing (as I understand it) is pushing changes stored in the managedObjectContext to the persistent store.

Try `[[document managedObjectContext] setUndoManager:nil]` (or create a new managedObjectContext for the import and set its undoManager to nil, if your `document.managedObjectContext` is the 'main' managedObjectContext and you don't want to turn off undo registration.

Comment: I already set the undoManager to nil. Additionally this is on iPhone and I think that by default the undoManager is nil.